# react-native. Default parameter type ?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am learning React-native.

I saw a following code on [ListView sample page of facebook.](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#content)

```
_renderRow: function(rowData: string, sectionID: number, rowID: number) {
....
```

By the way, i have never seen this syntax : ***'rowData:string'***

what is a semicolon(:)?

Is this syntax for parameter type checking?

Is this ES6 syntax?

Answer (score 1):

These are type annotations for the [flow](http://flowtype.org/) static type checker tool.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like TypeScript. See [this site](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) for details.

Answer (score -1):

Since React-native is based on Javascript language, the above syntax signifies declaring a property of a Object which can be of :

1.primitive type-(number,boolean,undefined or null)

2.string

3.Array

4.reference of another object

5.reference to a function (this is what is done in your mentioned code syntax)

Basic syntax of defining Object in JS:

var a = 
         { key1 : 1,//type number

```
       key2 : "this is a string type",//type string

       key3 :{key4:67,key5:function(){return "object inside object"}} // type Object

       key6 : function(){
              console.log('defined a function');
              }// type function
     }
```

Now in JS(javascript), every data structure can be dynamically typecasted to Object which is just a key-value pair.

You can through basic object defining tutorial from w3school:

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp